# Ads are not showing up-Adwhril,Admob

Tags: android, admob

I implemented Adwhirl but no ads are appearing

Below is my xml code of the linearlayout inside which im adding my AdWhirl Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Below is my code where in creating Adwhril Layout and adding it to the LinearLayout "ll_ad":

AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);

```
    AdWhirlTargeting.setAge(23);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setGender(AdWhirlTargeting.Gender.MALE);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setKeywords("online games gaming");
    AdWhirlTargeting.setPostalCode("94123");
    AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(false);

    AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this,
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int diWidth = 320;
    int diHeight = 52;
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(this);
    adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth((int) (diWidth * density));
    adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight((int) (diHeight * density));
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_ad);

    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, layoutParams);
    layout.invalidate();
```

Below is the logcat messages:

```
09-05 23:09:39.055: I/AdWhirl SDK(278): Creating adWhirlManager...
09-05 23:09:39.055: D/AdWhirl SDK(278): Locale is: en_US
09-05 23:09:39.105: D/AdWhirl SDK(278): Hashed device ID is: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
09-05 23:09:39.105: I/AdWhirl SDK(278): Finished creating adWhirlManager
09-05 23:09:39.154: D/AdWhirl SDK(278): Prefs{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}: {"config": "{"extra":{"location_on":1,"background_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":0,"green":0,"blue":0,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":30,"transition":8},"rations":[{"nid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","type":20,"nname":"zestadz","weight":50,"priority":2,"key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},{"nid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":50,"priority":1,"key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]}
09-05 23:09:39.154: D/AdWhirl SDK(278): ", "timestamp": 1346886053654}
09-05 23:09:39.164: I/AdWhirl SDK(278): Stored config info not present or expired, fetching fresh data
09-05 23:09:39.284: D/AdWhirl SDK(278): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
09-05 23:09:39.304: D/AdWhirl SDK(278): Received jsonString: {"extra":{"location_on":1,"background_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":0,"green":0,"blue":0,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":30,"transition":8},"rations":[{"nid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","type":20,"nname":"zestadz","weight":50,"priority":2,"key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},{"nid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":50,"priority":1,"key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]}
09-05 23:09:39.374: I/AdWhirl SDK(278): Rotating Ad
09-05 23:09:39.384: D/AdWhirl SDK(278): Dart is <11.333519576064566> of <100.0>
09-05 23:09:39.384: D/AdWhirl SDK(278): Showing ad:
09-05 23:09:39.384: D/AdWhirl SDK(278):     nid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
09-05 23:09:39.384: D/AdWhirl SDK(278):     name: admob
09-05 23:09:39.384: D/AdWhirl SDK(278):     type: 1
09-05 23:09:39.384: D/AdWhirl SDK(278):     key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
09-05 23:09:39.384: D/AdWhirl SDK(278):     key2: 
09-05 23:09:39.384: D/AdWhirl SDK(278): Valid adapter, calling handle()
09-05 23:09:39.584: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2017 objects / 531040 bytes in 159ms
09-05 23:09:39.594: E/Ads(278): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenLayout.
09-05 23:09:39.594: E/Ads(278): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include uiMode.
09-05 23:09:39.594: E/Ads(278): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenSize.
09-05 23:09:39.594: E/Ads(278): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include smallestScreenSize.
09-05 23:09:39.594: E/Ads(278): You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges.
```

I have declared AdActivity in my AndroidManifest but its still shows as an warning in LogCat.Also i tried to add uiMode,screenSize etc in configChanges but it was giving me errors.Following the code which shows the decalration of AdActivity in Android Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

Thank You!!

Comment: What is your SDK level. Also without AdWhirl, were you able to get AdMob ads?

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for the response.SDK level is 8 and i haven't tried admob ads without adwhril yet.

Comment: AdMob requires a target SDK level of 13. See: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ I would advise to get AdMob working first then get AdWhirl working as AdWhirl is for when you have multiple Ad SDKs in your app.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for your response.I'll set my target SDK to 13.Also can you please tell that will this have any bad effect on app when its installed on the device which runs Android 2.2(SDK 8)?

Comment: Shouldn't as long as your min SDK is at least higher than 3 per AdMob's requirements.

Comment: Im using 2 Ad Networks thats why im trying to use Adwhril

Answer (score 0):

Per [AdMob's documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/), you'll need to include additional configChanges.  Your AdActivity in the manifest should look like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

You should also consider using [AdMob Mediation](https://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2413211&topic=2403413&parent=1307209&rd=1) instead of AdWhirl going forward.  AdMob Mediation is better supported and should have more ad networks integrated into it.